# Using python libraries without root privileges, on a separate version of python than what is installed under root?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, package, virtualenv

Background: I'm doing some large simulations in Python 2.7 using brian2, numpy, cython, and hdf5.  So far I've been running them on my personal laptop (running Ubuntu), but I would like to run them on my lab desktop instead (running CentOS 7.1).  Problem is, I do not have root privileges, pip and easy_install are not installed.

I've tried downloading pip as a tarball and installing it manually, which worked, but I wasn't able to install anything because of an error about "unable to compile Python.h, you may need to install python-dev."

I've tried downloading python2.7-dev from source and compiling it, which worked, and it runs, but whenever I try to use it, it can't find the built-in packages.  When I try to run pip using my compiled version of python, I get "Import Error: No module named pkg_resources."

I've tried creating a virtualenv (using --no-site-packages) on my laptop, installing the packages I need, and then zipping it up and sending it to my work PC, but python is never able to find the packages I installed.

I think what I need to do is get my computer to forget about the installed version entirely, and work only with the version I compiled from source (in my ~/.local directory).  Is this possible?  If not, is there a better way to accomplish my goal?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to specify the interpreter to use when you run your scripts

Comment: I've tried "python myscript.py", "~/venv/bin/python myscript.py", and "~/.local/bin/python myscript.py" and none of these work.